# How to access a control in the parent Winform from a child Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form that executes this code upon a button click:

```
childForm frm = new childForm();
frm.ShowDialog();
frm.Close();
```

So when the childForm opens, I want to copy some data from a ListBox control on the parent to display and use it in a ListBox in the childForm.  So, ideally, I would like to refer to the parent form in such a way to do this, but every approach I've tried fails.  Seems like it would be easy. The childForm is not a MdiForm.

Answer (score 2):

The `ListBox.Items` collection can hold pretty much anything, so I'd recommend modifying the child form to accept a collection of whatever type you're populating the `ListBox` with. That way, the child doesn't have to cast the items in the collection itself, and you can just do what you need with them.

Modify the child form to accept the data you want to pass:

```
public class childForm : Form
{
    private IEnumerable<SomeClass> itemsFromParent;

    public childForm(IEnumerable<SomeClass> itemsFromParent)
    {
        ...
        ...
        this.itemsFromParent = itemsFromParent;
    }
}
```

Then pass the collection to the child:

```
using (var frm = new childForm(yourListBox.Items.Cast<SomeClass>()))
{
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: +1 for the only answer that addresses both (a) separation of concerns and (b) memory management with a _using_ clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parent form (`this`) as a parameter to the child form's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Send `ListBox` Control data in the `ChildForm` constructor. Or you can send instance of parent form.

```
childForm frm = new childForm(ListBox lb);
frm.ShowDialog();
frm.Close();
```

**ChildForm**:

```
public partial class childForm: Form
{ 
    public childForm(ListBox parentlb)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //use parentlb, traverse through items 
        //or assign items to private member of this class

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Grant Winney* has already suggested a good solution that you can pass the collection or list directly into the your child form constructor. the another method is that you can create a property in child forma and access it from  outside the child form.

By creating property in child form allows you to get back the items from child form after form close.

```
public class childForm : Form
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }

    private void childForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         lstMyListBox.DataSource  = Items;
    }
}
```

Now you can assign the selected items of listbox(parent form) to the child form like this

```
List<stirng> lstItems  = new List<stirng>();
foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    lstItems.Add(item.ToString());
}

childForm frm = new childForm();
frm.Items = lstItems;
frm.ShowDialog();
frm.Close();
```